# Randomly sample rows from a file based on times in columns

Tags: python, csv, random, sampling

This is a bit complex, and I greatly appreciate any help! I am trying to randomly sample rows from a .csv file. Essentially, I want a resulting file of unique locations (Locations are specified by `Easting` and `Northing` columns of the data file, below). I want to randomly pull 1 location per 12 hour period per `SessionDate` in this file (12 hour periods divided into: between `0631` and `1829` hours and between `1830` and `0630` hours; Given as `Start:` and `End:` in Data File, below); BUT if any 2 locations are within 6 hours of each other (based on their `Start:` time), for that location to be tossed, and a new location to be randomly drawn, and for this sampling to continue until no new locations are drawn (i.e., sampling WITHOUT replacement).  I have been trying to do this with python, but my experience is very limited.  I tried first putting each row into a dictionary, and recently each row into a list, as follows:

```
import random
import csv

f = open('file.csv', "U")
list = []

for line in f:
    list.append(line.split(','))
```

I'm unsure where to go from here - how to sample from these lists the way I need to, then write them to an output file with my 'unique' locations.

Here is the top few lines of my data file:

```
SessionDate Start:  End:    Easting Northing
27-Apr-07   18:00   21:45   174739  9785206
28-Apr-07   18:00   21:30   171984  9784738
28-Apr-07   18:00   21:30   171984  9784738
28-Apr-07   18:00   21:30   171984  9784738
28-Apr-07   18:00   21:30   171984  9784738
```

It gets a bit complicated as some of the observations span midnight, so they may be on different dates, but can be within 6 hours of each other (which is why I have this criterion), for example:

```
SessionDate Start:  End:    Easting Northing
27-Apr-07   22:30   23:25   171984  9784738
28-Apr-07   0:25    1:30    174739  9785206
```

Comment: Is every alternating row in your csv file really a blank line?

Comment: How big is the CSV file-- that is, how many entries? Are we talking a couple hundred? Thousands? Millions?

Comment: Are the rows sorted somehow? (e.g. by `SessionDate`)

Comment: No, there are no blank lines in my CSV file, I was having trouble making it show up clearly.  The files are anywhere from a few hundred to a few thousand lines.

Comment: The rows are not sorted, but I could easily sort them before processing.

Comment: I feel like you need to try a bit more, what you literally have only shown that you can ope the file containing the data you need. We can help you but not do ALL of it for you for how specific this question is. It sounds like homework.

Comment: Look at `collections.groupby` and `random.choice`

Comment: BilliAm, feel free to not help me.  I am a wildlife biologist, not a programmer, and just trying to get some help here.  You don't need to be rude/stuck up about it.

Comment: kjc, what's your locale? USA? UK? Canada?

Comment: @kjc As a biologist, you are probably very comfortable with stats. If you are also trying to learn your first programming language, python might not be the best choice. Especially given your problem domain, and the type of analysis you may want to do, might I suggest switching to R?

Comment: If your problem is handling the date and computing differences between them, then python's [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution - I made a few changes to your data (location to make it easier to eyeball the results). I basically create a `dict` of dates pointing to another `dict` of locations which points to a list of selected rows.

```
data  = """SessionDate Start:  End:    Easting Northing
27-Apr-07   18:00   21:45   A  1
27-Apr-07   18:00   21:30   G  2
28-Apr-07   18:00   21:30   B  2
28-Apr-07   18:00   21:30   B  2
28-Apr-07   18:00   21:30   B  2
29-Apr-07   8:00    11:30   C 3
29-Apr-07   20:00   21:30   C  3
29-Apr-07   20:00   21:30   C  3
30-Apr-07   8:00   10:30   D  4
30-Apr-07   16:00   17:30   E  5
30-Apr-07   14:00   21:30   F  6
30-Apr-07   18:00   21:30   F  6
"""

selected = {}
for line in data.split("\n"):
    if "Session" in line:
        continue
    if not line:
        continue

    tmp = [x for x in line.split() if x]
    raw_dt = " ".join([tmp[0], tmp[1]]).strip()
    curr_dt = datetime.strptime(raw_dt, "%d-%b-%y %H:%M")
    loc = (tmp[-2], tmp[-1])

    found = False
    for dt in selected:
        diff = dt - curr_dt
        if dt < curr_dt:
            diff = curr_dt - dt
        # print dt, curr_dt, diff, diff <= timedelta(hours=12), loc, loc in selected[dt]            
        if diff <= timedelta(hours=12):
            if loc not in selected[dt]:
                selected[dt].setdefault(loc, []).append(tmp)
                found = True
            else:
                found = True
    if not found:
        if curr_dt not in selected:
            selected[curr_dt] = {}
        if loc not in selected[curr_dt]:
            selected[curr_dt][loc] = [tmp,]

# if output needs to be sorted
rows = sorted(x for k in selected for l in selected[k] for x in selected[k][l])
for row in rows:
    print " ".join(row)
```

Answer (score -1):

**This is not a complete answer, but something to point you in the right direction**

As I said in a comment, handling datetime objects in python is done with the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module. Here's a little example related to your problem:

```
from datetime import datetime

d1 = datetime.strptime("27-Apr-07 18:00", "%d-%b-%y %H:%M")
d2 = datetime.strptime("28-Apr-07 01:00", "%d-%b-%y %H:%M")

difference = d2 - d1

#Difference in hours
dH = difference.days*24 + difference.seconds/3600
```

Other than that, simply loop through the sorted file, after reading a whole 12H block, sample ramdomly, make sure your unique condition is met (if not repeat) and move on.